# Per URI based ACL for IIS?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, access-control-list

I have ASPX website running on Windows 2008 R2, I want to limit the access for several interfaces, but not all of them.

e.g  I have an interface `/admin` for website `www.contoso.com`, but I only want people from `192.168.X.X` to access this specific location. For the rest it's open to public.

But I checked the IIS configuration, looks like I can only set global IP acls with `IPv4 Accress and Domain Restrictions`, is there any other solutions?

[image]

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve here.  Can you give an example of what it is you'd like to be able to do?

Comment: @Xander yes, see my updates

Comment: Got it.  Answer added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right feature, it's just not terribly clear how to use it to do what what you need.  You can indeed use the IP Address and Domain Restrictions feature to restrict access to a single folder, there just isn't any UI that make it obvious that's what you're doing.

First, you highlight the folder that you want to restrict access to (admin, in this case) in the IIS Manager, and then any rules you add using the IP Address and Domain Restrictions feature will apply only to that folder.

So, once you've highlighted the folder, set the feature default to deny all, add an entry to allow your subnet, and you'll be set.